# Opera and older firefox versions compatibility issues

Tags: firefox, browser, cross-browser, position, opera

I have a little problem with the position of my menu in Opera and older Firefox versions: [www.fundatiacarmengolea.ro](http://www.fundatiacarmengolea.ro). I would be grateful if anyone could suggest me any way to solve it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u be more specific. looks fine in opera to me

Comment: @albert Yeah, seems like in some opera versions the menu is down under the text "Din suflet pentru suflet"